# PostgreSQL inheritance: Insert a parent's row into the child

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I have a row in the parent table that I want to have in the child table but without creating a duplicate in the parent.

Extended example from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities (
    idcity          serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name            text,
    population      float,
    altitude        int     -- in feet
);

INSERT INTO cities VALUES (1, 'San Francisco', 7.24E+5, 63);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES (2, 'Las Vegas', 2.583E+5, 2174);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES (3, 'Mariposa', 1200, 1953);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES (4, 'Sacramento', 3.694E+5, 30);

-- The capitals table inherits from cities table.
CREATE TABLE capitals (
    state           char(2)
) INHERITS (cities);
```

Let's say I just learned *Sacramento* is a capital, so I want it in my `capitals` table.
If I use a normal `INSERT INTO capitals`, I get a duplicate value in cities, which is not so useful.

```sql
INSERT INTO capitals VALUES (4, 'Sacramento', 3.694E+5, 30, 'CA');

SELECT * FROM cities WHERE idcity = 4;

idcity | name       | population | altitude
-------+------------+------------+---------
4      | Sacramento | 369400     | 30
4      | Sacramento | 369400     | 30
```

(As specified in the documentation, the inheritance leads to having a duplicate value for the primary key and I could avoid that with `FROM ONLY`, but that's not my issue.)

I guess I could have a trigger on `capitals` to delete the parent row when I insert into the child, but isn't there a built-in way of doing that?

Comment: No, because you're breaking the inheritance logic there. Does making city a capital means it stops being a city? But if you really need to achieve that, trigger is the way to go.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I mean the opposite: I want to make a city a capital without changing anything about it being a city (name, population, altitude...). How could I do that?

Comment: But that's exactly what you have now, without any triggers.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Well yes, but I end up with two _Sacramento_ in `cities`, one that is a capital and one that isn't.

Comment: Got you. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the explain plan that `select * from cities` is basically an UNION ALL:

```
explain
select  *
from cities;

Append  (cost=0.00..21.27 rows=1027 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on cities  (cost=0.00..2.07 rows=107 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on capitals  (cost=0.00..19.20 rows=920 width=4)

explain select idcity from only cities
union all
    select idcity from capitals

Append  (cost=0.00..21.27 rows=1027 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on cities  (cost=0.00..2.07 rows=107 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on capitals  (cost=0.00..19.20 rows=920 width=4)
```

Hence your options are either using `select distinct * from cities`, which will be similar to:

```
select idcity from only cities
union
select idcity from capitals
```

Or using a trigger, as we discussed in the comments above. But we concluded that trigger makes no sense in this specific case.

So, there's no built in way that I found to achieve that, except using distinct.